# Transparency of materials

Tags: visible-light, material-science, crystals

Is transparency of material has something to do with inter- or intra-molecular bonding? E.g. both graphite and diamond are carbon, but graphite is opaque and diamond transparent.

Answer (score 7):

Neither nor. Inter-, intra-molecular bonding types (van der waals, ionic, covalent, metallic bonding) are all playing minor or major role in a solid depending on its material (element mixture, inter-atomic distance, crystal lattice type...).

In the end the **dielectric function** will theoretically define the reflectivity, transparency, absorption of a solid for a specific wavelength of light for these types of bonding (ionic/electronic polarisation). Look at the picture and formula [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_function#Complex_permittivity).

**Transparency is mainly defined by free electrons, position of Fermi Energy & type of bandstructure in a solid**. For instance, **metals** (metallic "intermolecular" bonding) are often reflective and non transparent due to free electrons, their Fermi Energy is outside of eventual band gaps. Many **isolators** (ionic "intermolecular" bonding) have Fermi Energy within an energy band gap of >4 eV , but **optical photon energy is around 1 to 3 eV**. So electrons in valence band beneath the band gap cannot absorb these optical photons, the material is transparent. Many **semiconductors** have a band gap around only 1 eV, so their valence electrons can absorb photons.

Of course the main specific bonding types in an semiconductor will co-define Fermi Energy, band structure. But they are necessary, not sufficient factors for optical properties of solids. You can roughly classify solid types by their dominant bonding types (isolators-ionic/covalent, metals-metallic,...).

Comment: So what's happened to a photon that is not absorbed by a transparent material? I mean what is the interaction type between photon and atom when it feels transparency and go through?